# Spring AMQP + RabbitMQ RPC How to execute/delegate different methods in a class

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, amqp, spring-amqp

I spent the entire day trying to get this to work. I've been following the tutorial 5 & 6 for Spring AMQP in the RabbitMQ tutorials page.

Is it possible for a single class to execute a different method based on some property? E.g. Routing key?

I've tried this so far to no avail:

```
@RabbitListener(bindings = @QueueBinding(
        value = @Queue(value = "requests"),
        exchange = @Exchange(value = "ourexchange"),
        key = "doFunc1")
)
public String func1(long id) {
    System.out.println("func1 " + id);
    return "func1 " + id;
}

@RabbitListener(bindings = @QueueBinding(
        value = @Queue(value = "requests"),
        exchange = @Exchange(value = "ourexchange"),
        key = "doFunc2")
)
public String func2(long id) {
    System.out.println("func2 " + id);
    return "func2 " + id;
}
```

In my client I did this:

```
public void send() {     
    System.out.println(" [x] Get func1( account_id: " + accountId + ")");
    String response = (String) template.convertSendAndReceive
        ("ourexchange", "doFunc1", accountId);
    System.out.println(" [.] Got '" + response + "'");

    System.out.println(" [x] Get func2( account_id: " + accountId + ")");
    String response = (String) template.convertSendAndReceive
        (exchange.getName(), "doFunc2", accountId);
    System.out.println(" [.] Got '" + response + "'");
}
```

I've got it "somewhat" to work but it appears to work in a round-robin fashion where the first method is called then the next one.

I've already considered the explanation here: [Single Queue, multiple @RabbitListener but different services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45066315/single-queue-multiple-rabbitlistener-but-different-services)

But since the signatures of both methods look identical I'm not sure it's possible.

Do note that I'm a beginner to the concepts of AMQP (like I've just read about the basics today). Am I doing this right or am I misunderstanding the usage?

Comment: I'm sure you could figure out how to do this, but why would you want to? It is good design to have a single mapping between a function and its input/output messages. Having a single input object able to invoke multiple functions is certainly going to lead to bugs and difficulty troubleshooting down the road.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your comment. I'm not sure how a class with multiple functions can lead to bugs either. @themayer

Comment: There's nothing wrong with multiple functions in a class- but let's be clear, when you start using messages, you have to start thinking in terms of functional programming rather than pure object-oriented.

Comment: You should let RabbitMQ do its job and perform the routing for you. See my answer.

Comment: Now that makes more sense. I realized that AMQP has its own paradigms. But let's also not beat around the bush. Is this possible or not? I wouldn't mind switching the idea to try something else. It's all PoC at this point. @themayer

Comment: Well, I don't use Spring, so I may not be the best to say what is *possible*. I can only tell you that I would not allow my developers to do what you're proposing because it breaks the functional paradigm which is very bad when you're trying to keep your software interfaces simple and under configuration control.

Answer (score 2):

The `@RabbitListener` infrastructure doesn't perform routing based on the routing key. You should use a different queue for each method and let RabbitMQ do the routing at the exchange level.

Alternatively, if you **must** use a single queue for some reason, you can pass the `RECEIVED_ROUTING_KEY` as a `@Header` parameter to your listener and delegate to different methods from the listener.

> I've got it "somewhat" to work but it appears to work in a round-robin fashion where the first method is called then the next one.

That's because RabbitMQ sees 2 consumers and will round-robin the messages. You need to use 2 queues or a single method and do the routing therein.

Comment: Actually I wasn't sure if I should use the routing key. I was just wondering if a class' different methods could be delegated as you said. In any case I'll edit the title for clarity.

Comment: With both methods subscribed to the same queue, RabbitMQ will simply round-robin the messages (but the algo will be based on the prefetch).