# Spring AMQP RabbitMQ RPC - Queue with with some messages that do not expect a response

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am trying to create a priority RPC queue that can accept some messages that expect a response and some messages that do not expect a response.  The problem I am facing is that when I send messages with convertAndSend I get an error saying "org.springframework.amqp.AmqpException: Cannot determine ReplyTo message property value: Request message does not contain reply-to property, and no default response Exchange was set."  I know the issue is that the RPC queue is expecting a response, and the message just stays on the queue, but for these messages I do not want/need a response.  Any idea how I can work around this issue?

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: How about just return `null` for those messages which don't suppose to return reply?

Comment: The consumer still waits for a response.  I really want these consumers to be a void return so they do not wait.  I think I have found a solution... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45066315/single-queue-multiple-rabbitlistener-but-different-services.  Basically I can have different handler for different messages which is really what I need.

Comment: The solution in that link above worked for me.  Basically I have a class with RabbitListener, and different methods with RabbitHandler

Comment: That's cool! Place it below as an answer and I'll vote up. Then tomorrow you can accept it by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution recommended in this link worked for me: [Single Queue, multiple @RabbitListener but different services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45066315/single-queue-multiple-rabbitlistener-but-different-services). Basically I have a class with RabbitListener, and different methods with RabbitHandler